# Zend_Form default checked box issues

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-element

Racking my brains I have been through the zend documentation and crawled google but cant find the solution.  I have a form using Zend_Form and on initial page load I need the contact me checkbox checked by default.

I have the below code which is suppose to work I am told but doesnt for me.  Any one had any experience with this?

```
        $contactme = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('contactme','checked');
    $contactme->setLabel("Please untick box if you don't want to be updated with offers.")
             ->setAttrib('checked','checked')
             ->setCheckedValue(1)
             ->setUncheckedValue(0)
             ->setValue(1);
```

Cheers

John

Comment: I dont think I have explained correctly I need the box to be VISUALLY check which is normally checked="checked" The user has the choice to uncheck it.

Comment: UPDATE I have been give some code but still doesnt work how hard can this be?        $contactme = $this->createElement('checkbox','contactme');
        $contactme->setLabel("Please untick box if you don't want to be updated with offers.")                                  
                 ->setCheckedValue(1)
     ->setUncheckedValue(0)
     ->setChecked(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$form->addElement('checkbox', 'paid', array('value' => true/false));
```

Is the way i do it. You can set in the array all other attributes too.

Comment: you must decide for true or false, don´ t take both =)

Comment: I have heres the code:  $contactme = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'contactme', array('value' => true));

Comment: You use createElement. I dont know this function. Do you need the checkbox later in the code? You can use $form->addElement, as i show and later say $form->getElement('contactme'), so you dont need $contactme

Comment: It sets the value to 1 but I need the box to be visually checked so the user has the choice to uncheck it.

Comment: This effect should created by this use of the function. it works very well at my homepage.